# MSSQL 2005 function on MSSQL 2000: GROUP BY CAST(...) trouble

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, casting, group-by

I have written a function that summarizes the records of a table statistically. This function works fine under MSSQL 2005:

```
DECLARE
@start datetime, 
@final datetime, 

SET @start = '08.02.2012'
SET @final = '08.02.2013'

SELECT  
  CAST(
       FLOOR(ISNULL(col1,col2)/50) * 50 AS int
      ) AS [MyCol1],
  CAST(
       FLOOR(ISNULL(col1,col2)/50) * 50 AS int
      )+49 AS [MyCol2],    

 COUNT(*) AS [Anzahl],
CAST(AVG(col3) AS decimal(3,2)) AS [MyCol3]
FROM T
WHERE Time BETWEEN @start AND @final
GROUP BY 
  CAST(
     FLOOR(ISNULL(col1,col2)/50) * 50 AS INT 
  )
ORDER BY 1
```

Now I would like to use this function on MSSQL 2000 systems, but the Group By region seems to be wrong:

> The Column is invalid in the select list, because it is not contained in an aggregate 
>   function and in the GROUP BY clause.

Can someone help me?

Comment: Don't have 2000 handy to test on. Does `GROUP  BY CAST(FLOOR(ISNULL(col1, col2) / 50) * 50 AS INT), CAST(FLOOR(ISNULL(col1, col2) / 50) * 50 AS INT) + 49` work? Maybe 2000 doesn't have logic to detect that grouping by the first and the second is the same grouping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to solve this is with a subquery:

```
SELECT [MyCol1], [MyCol1]+49 AS [MyCol2], COUNT(*) AS [Anzahl],
       CAST(AVG(col3) AS decimal(3,2)) AS [MyCol3]
FROM (select t.*, CAST(FLOOR(ISNULL(col1,col2)/50) * 50 AS INT) as [MyCol1]
      from T
     ) t
WHERE Time BETWEEN @start AND @final
GROUP BY [MyCol1]
ORDER BY 1
```

It also makes the query more understandable.

Comment: Would it be best to have the `WHERE` clause in the subquery or does it not matter?

Comment: @msmucker0527 . . . It should not matter.  (Decent) SQL engines don't actually instantiate a subquery as a table.  It just describes the processing that is being done.  When adding columns, there is no problem.  If there were an aggregation, it would be better to have the `where` in the subquery for most databases.

Comment: @Panschi11291: The `t` (after the `)`) is an alias of the derived table (subselect). Derived tables must have aliases in SQL Server.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Is the "t" in this case an alias for my table "T"?

I try it!